# How to implement shimmer effect in flutter for both Android and IOS?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to add a shimmer effect on my app while its loading. how to implement it on flutter for both Android & IOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) plugin which is available on the pub dev website.

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer

```
    Shimmer.fromColors(
                      baseColor: Colors.grey,
                      highlightColor: Colors.white,
                      period: const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
                      child: Text("HELLO"),
                      ),
```